# 2D tile based Cave Generator

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

My friends and I have been developing a 2D Tile based XNA game in C#. We have a world generator and are looking to implement caves into it. I found [this](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php/Cellular_Automata_Method_for_Generating_Random_Cave-Like_Levels) article, But its in C++. I'm not looking for exact code, but if anyone has any advice on making my own, or a similar method it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Perlin Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) it would work perfectly for this situation. Here is an implimentation : [C# Perlin Noise](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid9BA6F18AFE15A91665FC898E2E978E3241346AC6.aspx?s=%22Eran%20Kampf%22)

Do you have any images of what your game looks like? If you do, post a level so we can better see what you are trying to do.

Comment: We already have Perlin Noise for the terrain, but we need it for caves. Does that code contain cave generation?

Comment: You just need to add a filter so that any value below a minimum is ground and the rest is air.

Comment: Here is an example of someone using it for caves in 2D: http://josephknight.com/2d-cave-generator-looking-good/